# Let the OCaml code fit input as either int or list

Tags: tree, ocaml

```
let rec fold_inorder f acc t =
  match t with
  | Leaf           -> acc
  | Node (l, x, r) -> 
      let ar = fold_inorder f acc r in
      let an = x :: ar in
      fold_inorder f an l;;
```

I'm trying to print the infold of a tree as following :

```
assert (
  fold_inorder
    (fun acc x -> acc @ [x])
    []
    (Node (Node (Leaf, 1, Leaf), 2, Node (Leaf, 3, Leaf)))
  = [1; 2; 3] ) ;

assert (
  fold_inorder
    (fun acc x -> acc + x)
    0
    (Node (Node (Leaf, 1, Leaf), 2, Node (Leaf, 3, Leaf)))
  = 6 )
```

The first one worked, but second I got this error:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a List.t = 'a list
```

So how can I adjust it to fit either int or list?

Comment: Play the game... `Spot The Difference` between the two `assert` calls....Hint:- There are 2!!!

Comment: Notice that in the ````fold_inorder````, the parameter ````f```` is not used (other than in recursive calls). This can't be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing

```
    let an = x :: ar in
    fold_inorder f an l
```

you are building a list accumulator using the `List.cons` function.

This is not fold but a `to_list` function which is a special case of fold.

Hint: you need to use the `f` function in the body of `fold_inorder`.

Comment: I think he is complaining about the `assert`... :-)

Comment: The real error is unrelated to the asserts. Those asserts are just checking that that the implemented function is a fold.